# How do I make the indicator ATR2 daily /2 + daily low?

Tags: pine-script

I wonder if there is some friendly soul that could help me with forming this indicator: `ATR2 daily/2 + Daily Low`.  I don't have the skill to make it but I have some code that "should" work.

```
//

=3 study(“Fiddy”, overlay=true)

t = time(“1440”, session.extended) // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use “0930-1600” as second session parameter

//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

//plotshape(is_first, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown)

day_high = na day_low = na

if is_first and barstate.isnew

day_high := high
day_low := low

else day_high := day_high[1]
day_low := day_low[1]

fiddy (ATR2 daily /2)= (max(day_high, close[1]) + min(day_low, close[1]))/2
fiddy2 = (max(day_high, close[1]) – min(day_low, close[1]))*0.618 + day_low
fiddy3 = (max(day_high, close[1]) – min(day_low, close[1]))*0.382 + day_low

if high > day_high day_high := high

if low < day_low day_low := low

plot(fiddy, color=red, title=”fiddy”)
plot(fiddy2, color=orange, title=”fiddy618″)
plot(fiddy3, color=orange, title=”fiddy382″)
plot(day_high, color=lime, title=”day_high”)
plot(day_low, color=lime, title= ‘day_low’)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully give you something to work from:

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Fiddy", overlay = true)

atr_Length = input(20, "ATR length", minval = 2)

// Fetch daily high, low and ATR values.
dayHiRaw    = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dayLoRaw    = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dayAtr      = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", atr(atr_Length)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Save higher/lower hi/lo.
var dayHi = 0.
var dayLo = 10e20
dayHi   := max(dayHiRaw, high)
dayLo   := min(dayLoRaw, low)

fiddy1  = dayAtr / 2 + dayLo
fiddy2  = (dayHi - dayLo) * 0.618 + dayLo
fiddy3  = (dayHi - dayLo) * 0.382 + dayLo

plot(fiddy1,    "fiddy1",   color.orange)
plot(fiddy2,    "fiddy2",   color.maroon)
plot(fiddy3,    "fiddy3",   color.fuchsia)
plot(dayHi,     "dayHi",    color.lime)
plot(dayLo,     "dayLo",    color.red)
plot(dayHiRaw,  "dayHiRaw", color.lime, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(dayLoRaw,  "dayLoRaw", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

[EDIT 2019.08.31 22:56 — LucF]

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Fiddy", overlay = true)

// Fetch daily high, low and ATR values.
dayHiRaw    = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dayLoRaw    = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dayClRaw    = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", close[2], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Save higher/lower hi/lo.
var dayHi = 0.
var dayLo = 10e20
dayHi   := max(dayHiRaw, dayClRaw)
dayLo   := min(dayLoRaw, dayClRaw)

fiddy1  = (dayHi + dayLo) / 2
fiddy2  = (dayHi - dayLo) * 0.618 + dayLoRaw
fiddy3  = (dayHi - dayLo) * 0.382 + dayLoRaw

plot(fiddy1,    "fiddy1",   color.orange)
plot(fiddy2,    "fiddy2",   color.maroon)
plot(fiddy3,    "fiddy3",   color.fuchsia)
```

Comment: Thank you LucF. Tried yours but the highest/lowest price lines follow the price for some reason.. Here is how it should look like: https://www.prorealcode.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Dz7tvH4WsAIXnMC.jpg I have the correct code in ProRealTime language, do you think you can translate it?  htr = Dhigh(0)
ltr = Dlow(0)
 
fiddy = (max(dhigh(0), dclose(1)) + min(dlow(0), dclose(1)))/2
fiddy2 = (max(dhigh(0), dclose(1)) - min(dlow(0), dclose(1)))*0.618 + dlow(0)
fiddy3 = (max(dhigh(0), dclose(1)) - min(dlow(0), dclose(1)))*0.382 + dlow(0)

Comment: Impossible to compare to a reference for results, as the chart you sent has no ticker, no timeframe and no date. Edited my answer with a revised version of code. It gives you something you will be able to modify to your liking, if needed. Good luck.